# What is difference between changing magnetic field and changing magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

In some books when it comes to electromagnetic induction is mentioned the term changing magnetic field and into other changing magnetic flux so I'm interested in whether there is a difference or is it one and the same thing?

Comment: The magnetic field $\vec B$ is related to the magnetic flux $\Phi$ by the equation $\Phi = \vec B \cdot d\vec A$ where $d\vec A$ is the area through which the magnetic field is passing.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a magnetic field refers to he field itself, while changing the flux changes the "amount", of magnetic field going through a give area.

Changing a magnetic field could be achieved by changing the direction of a permanent magnet (as magnetic fields are vector quantities), or by pumping more current through an electromagent. That is to say, anything which changes the magnetic field lines changes the magnetic field itself.

Changing the magnetic flux however, refers to changing the "amount", of magnetic field passing through a given area. Consider the area enclosed by a loop opf wire. The flux through the loop could be changed by moving the loop into and out of a permanent magnetic field. The field itself doesnt change, just the amount of field lines going through the area.